# How to fix mobile safari address bar floating in the wrong place?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I have an iPhone 13, iOS v 16.1.1, and the address bar in safari floats over the navigation controls. See attached screen shot. [image: No safari! That's a bad safari!]

I can still hit the buttons but the hit box is very thin. The refresh button's hit box is not where the icon is but in the empty space where the address bar is supposed to be.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Try killing the Safari App and restarting it.  I have tried unsuccessfully to reproduce this and cannot

Comment: Killing the app fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Go ahead and write and answer and leave a comment to notify me….I’ll upvote!

Comment: @Allan it's done!

Comment: Awesome.  Upvoted.  Welcome to Ask Different!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Killing the app and restarting fixed this problem.